# Connect a "dump" USB-printer on macOS (High Sierra)

Tags: usb, high-sierra, printing, driver

The printer is a ticket printer (Epson TM-u220) and I have a Java App talking directly to the printer device at `/dev/tty(xxx)` on Linux and Unix without any special installed drivers.

On macOS, I can see the printer device with the `ioreg -p IOUSB` command, but there is no `/dev/tty(x)` associated with this device.
I can't find a driver on Epson's website for the TM-U220 for macOS (only Windows and Linux are supported). Also, I don't want one; a simple USB serial driver with a corresponding /dev/ttyUSBxx is all I need.

How do I associate a character device under `/dev/` for this printer?